# Is there a way I can reduce the number of if statements used?

Tags: c#, if-statement

So essentially I am trying to reduce the amount if if statements used.

**I need the message to be specific to both certificate types.** That's what's causing the problem. I could use || and && operators but then I would need the message to be a bit vague which i don't want.

Switch statements don't work because i'm using > and <
I have tried using ? but couldn't get my head around it.

```
if (compatibilityCerts > 2 && nonCompCerts > 2)
{
    rtbSummaryLog.AppendText(string.Format("There Are More Than Two Compatibility And Non-Compatibility Certificates On This Smart Card. {0}", Environment.NewLine));
    pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.Red;
    lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "More Than Two Compatibility And Non-Compatibility Certificates Detected";
        }
        else if (compatibilityCerts == 0 && nonCompCerts == 0)
        {
            rtbSummaryLog.AppendText(string.Format("There Are No Certificates On This Smart Card. {0}", Environment.NewLine));
            pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.Red;
            lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "No Certificates Detected";
        }
        else if (compatibilityCerts < 2 || nonCompCerts < 2)
        {
            rtbSummaryLog.AppendText(string.Format("There Are Certificates Missing On This Smart Card. {0}", Environment.NewLine));
            pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.Red;
            lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "No Certificates Detected";
        }
        else
        {
            if (compatibilityCerts > 2)
            {
                rtbSummaryLog.AppendText(string.Format("There Are More Than Two Compatibility Certificates On This Smart Card. {0}", Environment.NewLine));
                pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "More Than Two Compatibility Certificates Detected";
            }
            else if (nonCompCerts > 2)
            {
                rtbSummaryLog.AppendText(string.Format("There Are More Than Two Non-Compatibility Certificates On This Smart Card. {0}", Environment.NewLine));
                pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "More Than Two Non-Compatibility Certificates Detected";
            }
            else if (compatibilityCerts == 0)
            {
                rtbSummaryLog.AppendText(string.Format("There Are No Compatibility Certificates On This Smart Card. {0}", Environment.NewLine));
                pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "No Compatibility Certificates Detected";
            }
            else if (nonCompCerts == 0)
            {
                rtbSummaryLog.AppendText(string.Format("There Are No Non-Compatibility Certificates On This Smart Card. {0}", Environment.NewLine));
                pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "No Non-Compatibility Certificates Detected";
            }
            else
            {
                pctCertificateQuantity.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                lblCertificateQuantity.Text = "Number of Certificates is Valid";
            }

        }
```

Need to reduce if statements but maintain the specific messages.

Comment: Hmmm. If the code works then this is probably off-topic. Maybe try over on Code Review SE?

Comment: @jdv Unfortunately. there's not enough context in this code to get properly reviewed. It would get closed on CR.

Comment: That sounds like a hint to provide that context, because I think it would be needed for any review process. The only suggestion I can give you is write down, in English, the logic of key branches and see if any of the tests collapse. Also, static analyzers (and IDEs) can be very helpful.

Comment: We're not going to teach you Boolean maths

Answer (score 2):

You could use switch if your intention is to increase readability, by making use of Pattern Matching.

```
var pair = new {Compatibilty=compatibilityCerts ,NonCompatibilty=nonCompCerts };
switch(pair)
{
    case var item when item.Compatibilty > 2 && item.NonCompatibilty > 2:
    // Do Something
    break;
    case var item when item.Compatibilty == 2 && item.NonCompatibilty == 2:
    // Do Something
    break;
    case var item when item.Compatibilty < 2 && item.NonCompatibilty < 2:
    // Do Something
    break;
    case var item when item.Compatibilty > 2 :
    // Do Something
    break;
    case var item when item.NonCompatibilty > 2 :
    // Do Something
    break;
    case var item when item.Compatibilty == 0 :
    // Do Something
    break;
    default:
    // Do Something
    break;
}
```